# Code First EF6 - How to translate to a custom object thats not an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Stored Proc that's returning 2 columns. The first is an ID column to an entity (UserId) the next is a count of how many UserIds(Count).

In Code, I would like to translate this into a Dictionary, where `User` is an EF entity.

```
var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Translate<Dictionary<User, int>>(reader).FirstOrDefault();
```

This returns an empty Dictionary and it appears translate isn't working the way I'm hoping it would.

I'm guessing since I'm only returning the UserId it's not able to materialize into the complete User entity.

Can someone provide an example of how to get the end result I'm looking for?

Comment: One way of doing this would be: `dictionary.Keys.Select(k => context.UserEntitySet.Find(key))`. Note however that this can send up to `dictionary.Keys.Count()` queries to the database.

Comment: Are you using code first or database first? Instead of a stored procedure could you do it all in EF?

Comment: @PeterSmith I'm using code first. It's in a Stored Proc with a few other queries that also return similar info. I'm doing it all in one stored proc. to save the trips to the DB but I guess they could be split up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The supplied DbDataReader must contain data that maps to the requested entity type.

So there are two things wrong in your code:

- The type you're trying to materialize is a dictionary, not an *entity type*.
- And *if* is was an entity type, the reader wouldn't *contain data that maps to the requested entity type*, i.e. rows with values that correspond with the entity's properties.

You have to get the users by a separate query, using the id values that were returned from the stored procedure. Something along these lines:

```
var sprocValues = GetStoredProcedureValues();
// Let's assume this returns a List of Tuple<int,int>

var usrIds = sprocValues.Select(t => t.Item1).ToArray();
var users = dbContext.Users.Where(u => usrIds.Contains(u.UserID)).ToArray();
var result = from u in users
             join t in sprocValues on u.UserID equals t.Item1
             select new { User = u, Count = t.Item2 };
```